# WCF: Client sends the value but server receives empty string

Tags: c#, wcf

It looks like serverside cannot receive the passed values, requestVersion.Ping is empty.

```
   namespace Communication
   {
       public class DataForRequestVersion
       {
           public string Ping = "";
       }

       public class DataForResponseVersion
       {
           public string Pong = "";
           public string Version = "";
       }
   }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {    
        [OperationContract]
        Communication.DataForResponseVersion Version(Communication.DataForRequestVersion requestVersion);

    }

    //Server
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class ServiceImplementation : WCFSimple.Contract.IService
    {
       public Communication.DataForResponseVersion Version(Communication.DataForRequestVersion requestVersion)
       {

           //Here requestVersion.Ping is EMPTY

           Communication.DataForResponseVersion responseVersion = new Communication.DataForResponseVersion();
           responseVersion.Pong = requestVersion.Ping;
           responseVersion.Version = "MyApp v" + Settings.version; 

           return responseVersion;
       }

    }

    //Client makes a request here    
    Communication.DataForRequestVersion requestVersion = new Communication.DataForRequestVersion();
    requestVersion.Ping = DateTime.Now.ToString(Settings.DayTimePreciseFormat);    

    //Here requestVersion.Ping has a value

    Communication.DataForResponseVersion responseVersion = 
       Service.Version(requestVersion);
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

My application works very well, both sides communicate by passing custom data classes without any problem. However I tried to  modify test client which one only sends-receives current time as string and made its parameter a bit complex; from string to custom data class. Main solution's application can send Version request and receive the answer. So I think my little test client got a problem.

[image: My debug scren]

Here is the [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/MpCjLu35):

**2nd UPDATE:**

Some moderator doesn't allow me to answer my own question, I don't know why, I found a very similar question and the guy answered his own too. To help others next time I'm explaining the reason; I used **namespace** instead of creating **class**...And I fixed:

```
//namespace Communication
public class Communication
```

Comment: also... public fields are not hugely recommended... properties would be far preferable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to label your request (and response) classes with the `[DataContract]` attribute, and their properties with the `[DataMember]` attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class DataForRequestVersion
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Ping = "";
}
```

Comment: Strange but my app. has no [DataContract] attribute and other services work as well.

Comment: Make sure you hava a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` to find the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try using `[DataContract]` on your Data...classes... and `[DataMember]` on their fields...

Answer (score 0):

Change the fields in DataForRequestVersion DataForResponseVersion classes to properties. By Default DatacontractSerializer will serialize public properties.